# Order and Degree of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am unable to find the order and degree of the following differential equation:

$x^2(dx)^2 + 2xy dx dy + y^2(dy)^2 - z^2(dz)^2 = 0$

My approach:

Take the term $z^2(dz)^2$ to right hand side and then divide throughout by $(dz)^2$

we get  $$\mathrm{\dfrac{x^2(dx)^2}{(dz)^2} + \dfrac{2xy\ dx \ dy}{(dz)^2} +\dfrac{y^2(dy)^2}{(dz)^2} = z^2}$$

By seeing this, we can deduce that order is 1 and degree 2. But when I am looking at the middle term it contains dx dy/(dz)^2 term which is a term of order 2 and hence degree 1. Well am I right here? Is there any other way of finding the degree and order of this total differential equation? Do suggest, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Here order is 1 and degree is 2.

As we can write the above differential equation as

$\mathrm x^2{\left(\dfrac{dx}{dz}\right)^2 + 2xy\left(\dfrac{dx}{dz}\right)\left(\dfrac{dy}{dz}\right) +y^2\left(\dfrac{dy}{dz}\right)^2 = z^2}$